# Is it possible to integrate Outlook Social Connector with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ms-office, exchangewebservices, outlook-2013

I'm currently investigating the possibility to connect rails applicatrion with exchange for getting user information. I think to create rails page with user profile, and get profile information from exchange.

I found this: [Outlook Social Connector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee829696%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

As I understand, this is an API for getting information about user (contact list, updates, new e.g.) from exchange, isn't it?

So, please, help me to understand this thing...

Is it possible to get facebook-updates of my outlook-contacts using some of EWS/Social Connector APIs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Outlook Social Connector is a way that Outlook can connect to social networks. It sounds like you want to access data in the Exchange server. Have you looked at the [REST APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog)? There's a Rails sample here: https://github.com/jasonjoh/o365-vcftool. The code from that sample is also wrapped in the [ruby_outlook gem](https://github.com/jasonjoh/ruby_outlook).

Comment: I already use exchanger gem in my project, and actually currently I am searching for an EWS API to get outlook contacts and news. do you know, can I get from OSC some data? does some API for getting favorite contacts and news exists? In any case thank you for your answer

Comment: AFAIK there is no API to target that data. If OSC puts it into Exchange, it's likely there, the trick would be knowing how to get to it. You might want to explore with EWSEditor (http://ewseditor.codeplex.com) to see what you can turn up.